# stop junit class from autodeploying

Tags: java, eclipse

I am testing my eclipse web project on Jboss which I have set up in an integrated environment in Eclipse.

I have set the hot-deploy flag to yes, for development reasons.

However since the junit branch is under the same source tree, my server keeps restarting when I change my unit tests.

Is there any way to ignore a folder under src?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put your unit tests in a separate source folder named `tests`.